# Code not working for user toto input A's or B's and it to swap to all A's

Tags: python

I have created part of a code where the user inputs either letter 'A's or 'B's. The aim is for the program to say if the letters can be swaped to become all letter 'A's where the user has to input the size of swaps that can occur.

For example if the user inputs AABB and with a swap size of 3 the output should be BBAB where the two 'A's became 'B's and the one 'B' became an 'A'.

Currently my code doesn't seem to replace the letters and swap them where it says there is an error.

My code is below:

```
row = input('Enter the row and the side (A/B): ')
swap = int(input('How many places can be swapped? '))

if row[0] == B and row[swap] == B:
  row[0] = replace('B' , 'A') 
  row[swap] = replace('B' , 'A') 
  print(row)
```

Currently the code outputs the following:

```
Enter the row and the side (A/B): BBAA
How many places can be swapped? 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
    if row[0] == B and row[swap] == B:
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

The code should've outputted AAAA.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to quote the string: `if row[0] == 'B'`

Comment: Strings are immutable, you can't assign to `row[0]` or `row[swap]`. Either change `row` into a list, or assign to the entire variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

- Your condition check is wrong. `if row[0] == B and row[swap] == B:`. Here `B` is not a variable but a string literal. Hence you should use `'B'`. With that corrections also, the code doesn't work.

You can use `maketrans` and `translate`:

```
row = input('Enter the row and the side (A/B): ')
swap = int(input('How many places can be swapped? '))

table = row.maketrans('AB', 'BA')
s = ''

for i in range(swap): 
    s += row[i].translate(table)
row = s + row[swap:]

print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous answers strings are immutable and you did not have a variable A or B. Thus I converted them into a String literal. And the initial input is converted into a list.

```
row = list(input('Enter the row and the side (A/B): '))
swap = int(input('How many places can be swapped? '))

for x in range(swap):
    if row[x] == 'A':
        row[x] = 'B'
    else:
        row[x] = 'A'
print(''.join(row))
```